# Array for javascript

Tags: php

How to make the array for the code passthis= 1 if it have many data? Help me please.I work on this code for a month and I do not know how to do it.

```
function addRowHandlers() {
    var tbody = $("#employee-click");
    //document.getElementById("employee- click");    
    tbody.each(function () {
        $(this).on('click', function () {
            var passthis = 1;
            $.post("detail.php",
                    {sessionval: passthis},
                    function (e) {
                        window.location.href = "detail.php?no=" + passthis;
                    }
            );
        })
    })
}
```

Comment: Are you asking how to send an array of values using a post and then handle them with PHP ? (Really taking a shot in the dark here it's really unclear what you need)

Comment: yes something like that. actually, i want to try the array like for(int i=o;i<10;i++) and how to call the value so that when click the row it follow by the value start with  one

Comment: So basically you want to increment the number by one on each click or do you want to pass a different number based on which element was clicked?